# Getting None for logs in SimulationTransactionDetails

Tags: program-test

Hey so i am using the following API to execute a tx in a test done using program test crate
`banks_client.process_transaction_with_preflight_and_commitment_and_context(con, create_user_stake_tx, CommitmentLevel::Processed).await.unwrap();` however the return value returns a `BankBanksTransactionResultWithSimulation`
which has two fields
result and simulationdetails the latter contains logs but shows up as none even though my contract function logic  includes msg! logs

and this is the response
`this is the result, BanksTransactionResultWithSimulation { result: Some(Ok(())), simulation_details: None } why is simulation_details none here ?`

this is how i am calling it :

```
let con = Context::current();
let c = banks_client.process_transaction_with_preflight_and_commitment_and_context(con, create_user_stake_tx, CommitmentLevel::Processed).await.unwrap();
```

Comment: this is the result, ```BanksTransactionResultWithSimulation { result: Some(Ok(())), simulation_details: None }``` why is simulation_details none here ?

Comment: it would be preferred to update the description with new information rather than adding it as a comment

Answer (score 1):

The function that you're calling, `process_transaction_with_preflight_and_commitment_and_context`, only returns the simulation details if the transaction fails during the simulation.

If you want the simulation info, which includes the program logs, you'll need to use `simulate_transaction` directly, which was added in a recent release: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/a7e4df5d6e62b877aa0ec4bfcf5cef9317c2cb6d/banks-client/src/lib.rs#L330

Comment: am using the program test crate not the rpc client , it says it returns tx result even with process_transaction_preflight_commitment ... but it returns none for some reason but all the logs get printed while running the test "cargo test-bpf"
ref : https://docs.rs/solana-program-test/1.11.4/solana_program_test/struct.BanksClient.html#method.simulate_transaction_with_commitment_and_context

Comment: Program test gives you a `BanksClient`, which is linked in my answer